# sftp file size limit

Tags: sftp, files

There seem to be a file size limit for sftp transfer from the command line, if I try to download a 20 MB file it stops at 20% when the transfered data is larger than 4 MB:

```
/myfile.xml                             22% 4480KB 410.4KB/s   00:38 ETA
```

Is there a limit somewhere and how can you change it? I use a [scripted sftp connection with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251779/scripting-sftp-connection-with-expect-not-working). Downloading the file via [Nautilus file manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager%29) or sftp from the console without shell script and **expect** program both seem to work. The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect    
# usage: ./sftp_import.sh username host password filepath localpath

set username [lindex $argv 0]
set host [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set filepath [lindex $argv 3]
set localpath [lindex $argv 4]

spawn sftp $username@$host
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
expect "sftp>"
send "get $filepath $localpath\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye \r";
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like adding a timeout resolves the problem. The default expect timeout is [10 seconds](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html), which means at a rate of 400 KB/s, the timeout is trigged if 4000 KB = 4 MB is reached

```
set timeout 300
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit by default (as far as I am aware).

I would guess you are getting packet loss and timing out. Try adding -D.

`-D sftp_server_path Connect directly to a local sftp server (rather than via ssh(1)). This option may be useful in debugging the client and server.`

Source: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?1+sftp

I would probably copy it with rsync, `rsync -avrz --ignore-existing /folder/folder/folder username@whatever.com:/folder/folder/folder`